# Timestamps on netflow

Tags: linux, timestamp, netflow

I'm having a problem where I'm using a product called netflow, which reads network flow data. When I read some of the netflow data captured, the timestamps on the network flows aren't in milliseconds. I've showed a line of the data below;

> Date flow start||Duration||Proto||Src IP Addr:Port||Dst IP
>   Addr:Port||Packets||Bytes||Flows    1970-01-02   ||    05:51:34.210 ||
>   0.000 ||  TCP   ||    192.168.88.3:56457 ->      172.17.1.20:8080  ||       2  ||     82 ||    1

As you can see, the date flow start and the duration, while being listed to three decimal places, are only calculated to two. This is the same for every flow.

Could this be an operating system problem? I've seen pictures of the program work to three decimal places on google. I'm using Linux Mint, my processor is Intel® Core™ i3 CPU M 370 @ 2.40GHz × 4

Answer (score 1):

In nfdump *boot time is set one day back - assuming that the start time of every flow does not start ealier*

```
    boot_time = (uint64_t)(master_record->first - 86400)*1000;
```

and the epoch used is 000 UTC 1970 as described in [link to netflow packet](http://netflow.caligare.com/netflow_v5.htm)

And what actually is

**Date flow start =  1970-01-02 05:51:34.210**

**Duration        =  0.000**

which is fine.

so I guess this describes the date flow.

Also:  Line Format: -o line

This is the default format and shows one netflow record per line:

Date flow start         Duration Proto    Src IP Addr:Port         Dst IP Addr:Port   Packets    Bytes Flows

20012-08-30 06:59:52.338    0.001 UDP    36.249.80.226:3040  ->   92.98.219.116:1434         1      404     1

The date and Duration of the flow are given in millisecond resolution. so is upto 3 decimal places.

No, this is not the OS problem.

**P.S. nfdump gives the formatted output for date instead of millisecs.**

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand, do I need to change the 'boot_time'? When my nfdump flows come in the third decimal place in duration and date always reads as '0' i.e. 0.000, 7.670, 4.560, 0.090 etc, so I don't think its taking milliseconds into account